# (Stats?) Arrow next to the votes block on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

I've noticed an arrow next to the votes block on SO (it doesn't appear to be on the other sites):

[image]

It appears to do nothing and is not hyperlinked, but it does have the style name of `statsarrow` - what is it's intention? Is it for an exiting bit of new functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statsarrow` is named so because it's the arrow for the stats block.

It seems to be there purely to look nice; i.e. *Look! There's the question for which I'm the stats block!*

I would hypothesize that it doesn't appear on other sites because the background of the other sites' stats block isn't grey, and a white arrow on a white background doesn't make much sense. However, it's not appearing on MSO either, so I'm not sure that this is 100% correct.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it before and thought it was separate from the other block due to the spacing. In another browser there is no spacing so it must just be a UI decoration.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a balloon caption point to me.

I don't see a space as you do.